# FPGA - CPU Latency measurement with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, timer, arm, fpga

I am trying to measure Read/write Latency between an ARM CPU and An FPGA in the same board. I am wondering if using the global timer is sufficient to report this latency in term of clock cycles, because the ARM and the FPGA are running at different frequency.
My scenario is

```
    resetTimer();
    startTimer();
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++) { 
      T1 = readTimer();
      writeToFpgaIP(int* regAddress, int data);
      T2 = readTimer();
      storeInArray(T2-T1);
    }
    StopTimer();
    latency  = sum (array_write_timing[]) / 1000;
    -*-*-*-End algo-*-*-*
```

Comment: Embedded systems are benchmarked with oscilloscopes. Which is why you can't do any form of embedded systems programming without one.

Comment: Digital Signal Oscilloscope (or DSO in engineering world) is a very expensive unit. Decent logic analyzer (I'm a fan of Saleae) is ideal for this.

Comment: If you are designing an fpga board you have a scope, if this is an off the shelf that is another story.

Comment: In case you have interrupts in use, don't forget to disable them for the time of the actual measurement, i.e. before taking the first time-stamp, and enabling them again after taking the second time-stamp!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the time spans involved (msec, microseconds, nanoseconds) you may be losing granularity in the readTimer calls.  A more accurate way is to use a hardware probe and an oscilloscope.  Set the test point high on entry into the writeToFPGA routine and low on exit.  Newer scopes can average the pulse width for you, but even if you don't have that capability, you will see absolute times and get a feel for variability.

Answer (score 2):

Change your algorithm to be like this for more precision,

```
resetTimer();
startTimer();
T1 = readTimer();
for(i=0; i<1000; i++) { 
  writeToFpgaIP(int* regAddress, int data);
}
T2 = readTimer();
StopTimer();
latency  = (T1-T2) / 1000;
```

You can attempt to measure the loop overhead by creating another loop that mimics the existing loop and time it.  For example, if `writeToFpgaIP` is a function,

```
  dummyCall(int* regAddress, int data){}
  dummyWrite(int* regAddress, int data){volatile int foo = data;}
```

`dummyCall` is just to see the compilers function call overhead and `dummyWrite` is compare the FPGA bus versus your core memory (or cache). 
Examine the assembler to make sure the compiler hasn't optimized things away and double check it is similar to the benchmark loop.  You may have to fiddle with compiler options so that a loop with `dummyCall` (or `dummyWrite`) is structured just like `writeToFpgaIP`.

Using an oscilloscope is beneficial, but it will only measure timing on the FPGA side.  You can not scope what happens to the data after it hits the CPU/SOC pins.  So using both techniques can be beneficial; make sure they confirm each other.

If not, then the port/bus you connect the FPGA to may need some investigation on the ARM side to improve access.

Comment: When using a scope, try to find a signal(s) that give a transaction complete.  For example, if it is an AHB bus you can try `HCLK` and `HREADY`.  Using a scope can be complex in not everyone has a scope capable of capturing the signals and/or the bus may not give good information to trigger on.  If you can write arbitrary data to the FPGA, you can use this to help trigger a scope.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how the readTimer() calls are implemented (could be a simple local peripheral read), your benchmark as written in interleaving your critical write with other processing. Depending on the core, this could show up a single cycle (for the STR). By the time the loop comes round again, it's possible that the STR has completed.

it is unlikely that your benchmark represents the actual problem you're trying to address. Even if you repeat the STR in a loop 1000 times, you're still not observing the actual latency, you're now looking at the streaming bandwidth to the FPGA which is possible.

Depending on the system, latency means how fast (from a determined event) the core can trigger a response in the FPGA. Classically, this might be IRQ, pass some data to the FPGA, return a response, write to a peripheral (unless it's the FPGA driving the pins).

A slightly better approach might be to write data to the FPGA, read back an FPGA register, (volatile, device region), use the data, and put this in a loop.

Depending on the device memory system, this still might not give a result which relates to the performance of the system (Cortex-R8, Cortex-M0 will be in very different systems, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an external scope or logic analyzer, I tend to add performance measurement to the FPGA. That way, I can measure the total and average number of cycles for handling requests from the CPU and I can also measure the CPU overhead by performing back to back requests and measuring total elapsed cycles. I often also measure the quantity of data transferred in either direction.